# ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, mod-fcgid

A page is resulting in a 500 error and the log shows this:

```
[Wed Mar 20 11:19:23 2013] [warn] [client 127.0.0.1] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: ap_pass_brigade failed in handle_request_ipc function
```

It is occuring on a lemonstand website, when you try to view 90 products on a category page. The step from 60 per page to 90 appears to be too many, and it results in a 500 error.

The page loads for no more than around 4 seconds before the error, and there are many other websites running on the server which do not experience this issue.

I have so far assumed that this is due to environment settings, and not caused by Lemonstand. I have googled the heck out of this and tried various config settings to get it to behave, none have so far fixed it. Below is the current fcgid config, I have commented out some of the variables I tried changing.

Fcgid.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
AddHandler php-fcgi .php
Action php-fcgi /fcgi-bin/php-fcgi-wrapper
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
Alias /fcgi-bin/ /var/apache/fcgi-bin/

FcgidConnectTimeout 180
FcgidIOTimeout 600
FcgidBusyTimeout 3600
FcgidMaxRequestLen 226777216
FcgidFixPathinfo 1
#FcgidOutputBufferSize 65536
#FcgidProcessLifeTime 30
#FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess 500
FcgidIdleTimeout 60
#FcgidIdleScanInterval 1
#FcgidBusyTimeout 60
#FcgidBusyScanInterval 1
#FcgidInitialEnv PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS 100000

<Location /fcgi-bin/>
SetHandler fcgid-script
Options +ExecCGI
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Location>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I know this is 8 months old, but did you ever find a solution to this...?

Comment: Nope! Figured it was just some DB access issue, reduced the per page requests and the errors didn't seem to reoccur. Please post if you find out. Not working on this project anymore but it would be interesting to know if there is a solution! Lemonstand couldn't provide a solution to the problem either.

Comment: You need to increase Maximum request per process. To know how to do it read this doc http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#examples

Answer (score 2):

This is a `PHP-FCGI` limit error you're receiving. You'll need to adjust either the "`PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS`" variable inside the "fcgi-bin/php5.fcgi" file for the domain or "`FcgidMaxRequestsPerProcess`" variable inside the Apache config file.

http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#examples